# Script to take existing PDF file, clone to double 1/2 page format on output PDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf, dompdf

EDITTED: If there's any confusion involved, the image towards the bottom is portrait layout on the left, landscape layout on the right. Meaning, the pdf contents that were on the left hand side are to be cloned side by side to each other, into a landscape format.

The resources I'm using at the moment are FPDF, DOMPDF, and about to incorporate TCPDF into this project, coded in PHP.

I need to know if it's possible to use any of these resources, or any other resource for that matter, to take an existing PDF file and clone it to where it takes up exactly 2 half pages of the output PDF. The most crucial part about this is that there should be no borders/margins.

Does anyone have a script that can do this flawlessly?

Here's an image representation:

[image: Flipped Page]

Comment: Please explain properly what you are trying to do! How about making the left half of the result red and the right half blue and showing where they each came from in the original image and if they were rotated. Are you talking about multi-page PDFs? What OS and scripting language do you need?

Comment: @Marksetchell I just edited my question, but to answer through here, PHP. What I mean is the content that is on the right of the image (portrait style A4 page) is cloned to both sides of a single page, landscape layout, where the previous content is now side by side with each other. I'll change the image so it's more clear..

Comment: @Marksetchell I just editted it

Comment: So the right side of the original page is cloned and printed twice side by side on two pages. Where does the left side of the original page end up?

Comment: Your maths doesn't add up either. A4 will be 2480 pixels by 3508 pixels at 300 dpi. And Letter size will be 2550x3300 which will not accommodate half of A4 with no border!

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, the entirety of the original page (that's pictured as a portrait), gets placed on both half sides of another PDF that will render landscape. So, in the end, it will only be one page, that's lanscape, and half of it will be filled with the entirety of the previous page, and the other half will be as well

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I'm sorry, it's probably just Letter size then, which is 11x8.5 inches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at at [FDPI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi) (which is based on FPDF). The [simple demo](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/) shows importing a PDF into a portion of a page.

I haven't used it, but based on that demo you should be able to do what you want using something like the following:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI('L');
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("PdfDocument.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 150 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 150);
// use the imported page and place it at point 400,10 with a width of 150 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 400, 10, 150);

$pdf->Output();
```

(Note: this is completely untested and the fact that the width is in mm while the positioning is in PT makes this a rough estimate at best.)

Comment: great catch on "point"... for sure this is the position in the unit defined in the [constructor](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm).